# How do I remove my email address book from my iPhone 7 contact list?

Tags: iphone, contacts

I just got an iPhone 7. But my email address book has merged with my phone number contact list. How do I remove the email addresses?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Your question is a bit unclear.  Can you edit it to tell us what apps you're using and what you're seeing when you say it 'merged'?  Also, screenshots are helpful for others to understand what's happening.  - From review.

Answer (score 2):

iCloud for Web can be used to restore the contact list before merging. Go to [iCloud Settings](https://www.icloud.com/#settings) and under **Advanced** click **Restore Contacts**.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Contacts > Accounts and select the email account that is showing on your contacts.

Switch "Contacts" off on that account. It will warn you that those contacts will be deleted from your iOS device.

Tap on "Delete from my iPhone".

I recommend to chose one "email address book" and work with it so it becomes your phone/email/etc address book: this way you'll have a copy of your information synced and available in case your device has a problem, and it will simplify migration.

If your email contacts are from work, you can open an iCloud account or another email service to sync personal contacts.

You can browse selectively between contacts when you have more than one account source.

On the Phone or Contacts apps look for "Groups" on the top left of your screen.
You can select there between your different accounts Contacts.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this by clicking "groups" while in my contacts and turning off Yahoo. All of the email addresses were coming from Yahoo.